# Build tooltip notes inline instead of on document ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page loading more than 300 tooltips with about 1000 characters each.  The jQuery UI is doing all the work of creating these div elements. I'd like to know if I can build them inline, and keep them hidden, to speed up fragment caching, and then only attach the handler to the element read from the cache.

Here's the fairly simple JS code to create and handle the tooltips.

```
  $(function() {
    $(document).tooltip({
      tooltipClass: "notes",
      content: function (callback) {
        callback($(this).prop('title'));
      }      
    });
  });
```

And the simplified view code, which loads the notes for the tooltip into the title attribute of a sortable container.

```
.portlet
  .portlet-header
    # Some info
  .portlet-content(title="#{ t.notes if t.notes }")
    # more info
```

Fragment caching doesn't seem to help if the JS has to create hundreds of popup elements after I serve the basic info for each `.portlet` element.  I really appreciate your help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating the tooltips on-the-fly, eg. use hover to call a function which will create the tooltip.

Assuming all elements that need hover have class `portlet-content` here's something to get you started... try integrating the .tooltip inside the function. See the console.log for elements you can use).

```
$(function() {
    function doToolTip(e) {
        console.log("Event: ");
        console.log(e);
        console.log("Event target: ");
        console.log(e.target);
        console.log("Title of the target: " + e.target.title);
    }
    $(document).on("hover", ".portlet-content", doToolTip);
});
```

Comment: I think that's what I'm asking about. I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: How's your js/jquery skills?

Comment: Added a function that gets called on hover. The rest is up to you.